# Creating resolve option in directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using angular bootstrap tabs to display some section in one page. In order to not load everything at once, I created a directive to allow load a tab when clicked, it also support using a separate controller for each tab.

That way, I have a controller where the tabs are located, and for each tab I have a controller as well.

```
.directive('template', ['$templateCache', '$compile', '$http', function ($cache, $compile, $http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            var template = attrs['template'];
            var controller = attrs['controller'];

            if (template !== undefined) {
                var tpl = $cache.get(template);

                if (tpl) {
                    compile(tpl);
                } else {
                    $http.get(template).success(function (html) {
                        $cache.put(template, html);
                        compile(html);
                    });
                }
            }

            function compile(html) {
                var e = angular.element(controller === undefined || controller.length === 0 ? html : "<div ng-controller='" + controller + "'>" + html + "</div>");
                var compiled = $compile(e);
                element.replaceWith(e);
                compiled($scope);
            }
        }
    };
}])
```

Now I can use it like this:

```
//controller
$scope.data = something;
$scope.tabs = [
        {
            template: 'html-template-url',
            controller: 'controller-name',
            resolve: { //how o implement this?
                data: function () {
                    return $scope.data;
                }
            }
        },

//view
Some data: {{data}}
...
<uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" select="select(tab)">     
<div ng-if="tab.loaded" template="{{tab.template}}" controller="{{tab.controller}}"></div>
</uib-tab>
...
```

The problem is I need to pass some information from the main view, to the partial view in tab, as they are separated controller I can get it to know how to get this. I guess some kind of *resolve* property, but I've been trying with no success.

Could anyone please give me some advice?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using routes here (IE resolve) as opposed to directives?

Comment: Behavior similar to resolve, as used in routes is what I want to achieve. I want to be able to pass data through the directive to the view.